Xamarin.Forms with Shiny Jobs not working on iOS
I'm developing an app using Xamarin.Forms version 5.0.0.2662 and the Shiny library for periodic jobs (version 2.7.3). The periodic jobs work perfectly on Android devices, but they don't work on iOS. Instead, I receive the following error message:
ex {System.InvalidOperationException: ServiceProvider is not initialized - This means you have not setup Shiny correctly!  Please follow instructions at https://shinylib.net at Shiny.ShinyHost.get_ServiceProvider () [0x00007] in <c4b34a60966e4f8a972a9ce9769e4433…}
iOS Configuration
Here’s how I have configured the iOS AppDelegate:

[assembly: Shiny.ShinyApplication(
    ShinyStartupTypeName = "AppData.System.Startup",
    XamarinFormsAppTypeName = "AppData.System.App"
)]
namespace AppData.System.iOS
{
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            try
            {
                global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
                LoadApplication(new App());
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }

        public override void PerformFetch(UIApplication application, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
        {
            ShinyHost.Resolve<IJobManager>()
                .RunAll()
                .ContinueWith(task =>
                {
                    if (task.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
                        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
                    else
                        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.Failed);
                });
        }
    }
}

Xamarin.Forms Startup
The startup configuration in my Xamarin.Forms project is as follows:
namespace AppData.SystemUsers
{
    public class Startup : ShinyStartup
    {
        public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IPlatform platform)
        {
            services.UseJobs(true);
            services.UseNotifications();

            services.RegisterJob(new JobInfo(typeof(SyncJob), "SyncJobs")
            {
                Repeat = true,
                BatteryNotLow = false,
                DeviceCharging = false,
                RunOnForeground = true,
                RequiredInternetAccess = InternetAccess.Any
            });
        }
    }
}

Job Implementations
This is the implementation of my job. On Android, it successfully sends a message via a POST request to the API. On iOS, however, it fails with the aforementioned error:
public class SyncJobs : IJob
{
    private readonly INotificationManager notificationManager;
    private static bool IsRunning = false;

    public SyncJobs(INotificationManager notificationManager)
        => this.notificationManager = notificationManager;

    public async Task Run(JobInfo jobInfo, CancellationToken cancelToken)
    {
        if (!IsRunning)
        {
            IsRunning = true;

            await APIServices.SendPostMessage(cancelToken, $"Init - iPhone");

            IsRunning = false;
        }
    }
}

Info.plist
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>processing</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>    
</dict>
</plist>

Execution in App.xaml
In App.xaml, I am forcing the execution of the job, and this is where the exception occurs:
Shiny.ShinyHost.Resolve<Shiny.Jobs.IJobManager>().Run("SyncJobs");

Does anyone know why the service provider initialization fails on iOS and how to fix this issue? I've already tried following the Shiny library setup instructions but can't seem to figure out what's missing for iOS.
I am testing on a real device, not on a simulator.

I managed to resolve this issue in the AppDelegate -> FinishedLaunching.
I added this code right at the beginning, and it worked:
this.ShinyFinishedLaunching(new Startup());

